# How to get combination of Measure count using same dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap, cube

how can i get all the combination of Dimensions Measure count in MDX. In the Below image I'm getting individual value measure count but how can i get combination of values measure count.Say for example i have got the individual value count for 262,210 and 198 DrKey Dimension.I would need value count combination like 
1) 262 and 210 along with measure count 
2) 262 and 198along with measure count 
3) 198and 210 along with measure count 
4) 262,210 and 198 along with measure count 
[image]

My below query :

```
WITH 
  MEMBER DrKey AS 
    [DimPopulation].[Population Key].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DrList] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      {[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[262], [DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[210]}
     ,[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    DrKey
   ,[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
   ,DrList
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    {
      [DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[262]
     ,[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[210]
     ,[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[198]
    }
   ,[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [abc]
WHERE 
  (
    [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20141031]
   ,[DimReport].[Report Key].&[1]
  );
```

Comment: upped for such a beautifully laid out question (not actually read it yet!)

Comment: What is `DrList` ? A count?

Comment: DrList means comibination members measure count for example 262&210 along with measure count.

Comment: but you already have 262, 210 etc ON ROWS individually so maybe you need to take that section out?

Comment: Finally I found the solution using sets WITH 
  SET FirstSet AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      [DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key].MEMBERS
     ,(
        [Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
       ,[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[190]
      )
    )

Answer (score 1):

Is it still showing error?

```
//WITH 
  //MEMBER DrKey AS 
    //[DimPopulation].[Population Key].CurrentMember.Member_Key 

WITH
 MEMBER [Measures].[DrList] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
      {[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[262], [DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[210]}
     ,[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
    ) 


SELECT 
  {
    //DrKey,
   [Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
   ,DrList
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    {
      [DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[262]
     ,[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[210]
     ,[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[198]
    }
   ,[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [abc]
WHERE 
  (
    [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20141031]
   ,[DimReport].[Report Key].&[1]
  );
```

Comment: Just checking: SELECT {[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[262],[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[210]} ON 0, Measures.DrPatientKeyCnt on 1 FROM [abc]. Does it work fine?

Comment: Hi Sourav  thank u for your replay it will give me two sets of measure count. But i need all the combination of sets of measure count like below 262,
210,
198,
262&210,
210&198,
262&198,
262&210&198

Comment: I have an idea using below querry but still its giving me an error  in the iff clause... MEMBER [262and210] AS sum
    (
      [DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key].MEMBERS
     ,IIF
      (
        ([Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt],{[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[262],[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[210]}) <> 0
       ,
         1
       ,NULL
      )
    )

Comment: I was just doing basic troubleshooting. It's quite clear there's an issue with the calculated member [DrList]. Run it individually and probably you will get better idea on why it is erroring.

Comment: It could also be because you are having members from the same hierarchy in the member clause as well as ROWS. Could you have something equivalent instead of [Population Key] in the member's definition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66452/discussion-between-mohan111-and-sourav-agasti).

Answer (score 0):

Try just using `aggregate` function around the tuple:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER DrKey AS 
    [DimPopulation].[Population Key].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DrList] AS 
    AGGREGATE(        
      NonEmpty
      (
      {[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[262], [DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[210]}
     ,[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
      ) 
    )
SELECT 
  {
    DrKey
   ,[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
   ,DrList
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NonEmpty
  (
    {
      [DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[262]
     ,[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[210]
     ,[DimPopulation].[Population Key].&[198]
    }
   ,[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [abc]
WHERE 
  (
    [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20141031]
   ,[DimReport].[Report Key].&[1]
  );
```

Comment: With or without `AGGREGATE`, the default behavior in the tuple would be to aggregate, won't it?

Comment: I'm unsure about that Sourav - sometimes I am forced to use `Aggregate`.

Comment: i did not see any difference for above query though adding aggregate function still it says error. Its not giving two tuples measure count

Comment: @mohan111 I just added the aggregate function. I was just an idea.